# Can we store MultiDimentional Array In redis

Tags: redis

Is it possible to store multidimensional array in Redis hash

For example

```
HMSET('Marray','Name'=>"test12",
               "Age"=>"45",
               "Salary"=>"50000",
               "GENDER"=>array("M"=>"1","F"=>"2"))
```

Or is any other possibility to store the above values

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16094574/alternatives-to-nested-structures-in-redis/57856223#57856223) for how to save nested data structures to Redis.

Answer (score 10):

You can serialize that sub-array (as JSON, for example) and store it in a hash field. Redis doesn't support arbitrarily nested structures.

Or you can even serialize the whole structure and store it as plain string.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest storing the array in its own key (as a hash, sorted set, or list) and storing its key in your hash/records.  You'll presumably want to assign a prefix to all of those keys (so you can manage the keyspace.

Answer (score 0):

This page talks about this. Redis may not be the best suit for multidimensional data though. 
https://redis.io/topics/indexes